# SQL COUNT DISTINCT with CASE : How do i subquery without using exists?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, xml, mapping

**context:**
In SQL Server have a big XLSX file that i am mapping to an XML file. A column called 'referentie' gets different values each time. I need to count unique values and display a code accordingly . (Please note that is a subquery inside a bigger SELECT statement. I'm not able to add additional aggregate funcitons.)

1. I need to count the unique values of a JSON array input (Output is in XML). (done)
2. Display values depending on the retrieved unique count (issue)

**issue :**
In the query you'll see i have multiple COUNT DISTINCT CASES. SQL throws error which is normal :

`Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.`

**My query :**

```
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Referentie > 10 THEN N'CON1' END) AS [HEADER/CHECK],
                        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Referentie <= 10 AND Referentie > 29 THEN N'CON2' END) AS [HEADER/CHECK],
                        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Referentie <= 30 AND Referentie >= 50 THEN N'CON3' END) AS [HEADER/CHECK],
                        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Referentie <= 50 AND Referentie >= 500 THEN N'CON4' END) AS [HEADER/CHECK]
                FROM OPENJSON(@Json, N'$.Blad1')
                WITH (Referentie nvarchar(100) N'$.Referentie')) AS [HEADER/CHECK],
```

Question:

- What is the correct syntax here to make my logic work ?

**JSON in file  :**

```
@Json = N'{
   "Blad1":[
      {
         removed
      }
   ]
}'
```

Comment: If your subquery should be outputting XML, why does it not have `FOR XML` in it? It's putting a dataset, *not* XML (or another scalar value) and the error is **explicitly** telling you that isn't allowed.

Comment: Hi @Larnu . You can't know because the snippet is a subquery inside of a larger query which ends with the needed FOR XML clause. I have no issues in my I/O, i have issues with the syntax. I understand that i can't have multiple expressions inside of the query. But is wouldn't know how to fix it.

Comment: I can know, I can see in the snippet that you *end* the subquery and there is no `FOR XML`...

Comment: I don't understand where your heading at . You can't read the complete stored procedure i'm working with can you ? So i politely disagree, you ***can't*** know... My main query's structure is ```SET @xml = (SELECT allQueriesCombined FOR XML PATH(N''), ROOT(N'rootElement'),TYPE);```

Comment: If you are saying we can't understand because you haven't supplied the whole query that'd not our fault, that's yours... But even *if" your outer query had `FOR XML` that would not stop the error, due to your subquery returning a dataset.  Very likely you want `FOR XML PATH('CHECK'), TYPE) AS [HEADER]`, but what do I know, I don't understand and you won't give the full picture. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: You also end up with multiple columns of the same name, so unclear how you want that. And `Referentie` has strings in it so why are you comparing it to numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you are being somewhat unclear about what you are trying to achieve. You say you are managing to count unique values, but not display a value dependent on that.

Your code doesn't even manage that. What it actually does is check whether `Referentie` is within defined numbers (which makes no sense as it's a string), then distinct over a single string. Then it returns this multiple times, once for each parameter.

Instead, you need a *single* `COUNT (DISTINCT Referentie)`, which has a `CASE` around it checking how much it is.

There is another issue with your current code. The conditions `>` and `<` are backwards. And `< 29` should probably be `< 30`.

```sql
SELECT
  'SomeValue' AS xyz,
  (
    SELECT
      CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Referentie) < 10
          THEN N'CON1'
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Referentie) >= 10 AND COUNT(DISTINCT Referentie) < 29
          THEN N'CON2'
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Referentie) >= 30 AND COUNT(DISTINCT Referentie) <= 50
          THEN N'CON3'
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Referentie) >= 50 AND COUNT(DISTINCT Referentie) <= 500
          THEN N'CON4'
      END
    FROM OPENJSON(@Json, N'$.Blad1')
      WITH (
        Referentie nvarchar(100)
      ) AS j
  ) AS [HEADER/CHECK]
FROM (VALUES(0)) DummyTable(DummyValue)   -- don't know what the rest of your query is
FOR XML PATH(N''), ROOT(N'rootElement'),TYPE
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d6ddfd1fdc153c68cc596ff929136e55)

As a side point, if you really wanted multiple columns from a subquery, you would need to place it in a `APPLY`.

Comment: Thank you for this ! Also thank you for explaining where i went wrong. 
```Instead, you need a single COUNT (DISTINCT Referentie), which has a CASE around it checking how much it is.``` This is what i didn't know and helped me understanding my problem. +1 and marked as answer .

Answer (score 1):

I've put the first query in a CTE and then your conditions in the query following but the results are probably not what you are expecting. Firstly Referentie is alpha-numerique so I have just used the numeric part, secondly only one of the values you are testing is met.
I have therefore grouped by Referntie and shown the number of duplicates to make things clearer while you are refining your query.

> ```
> declare @json varchar(max);
> set @Json = ----   THE VALUE GIVEN IN THE QUESTION  ---
> ```

> ```
> WITH myJson as (
> select 
>   right(Referentie,7) Referentie
> FROM OPENJSON(@Json, N'$.Blad1')
>  WITH (Referentie nvarchar(100) ) AS [HEADER/CHECK]
> )
> SELECT
>   COUNT(*) "number",
>   Referentie,
>   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Referentie > 10 THEN N'CON1' END) AS [HEADER/CHECK],
>   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Referentie <= 10 AND Referentie > 29 THEN N'CON2' END) AS [HEADER/CHECK],
>   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Referentie <= 30 AND Referentie >= 50 THEN N'CON3' END) AS [HEADER/CHECK],
>   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Referentie <= 50 AND Referentie >= 500 THEN N'CON4' END) AS [HEADER/CHECK]
> FROM myJson
> GROUP BY Referentie
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> number | Referentie | HEADER/CHECK | HEADER/CHECK | HEADER/CHECK | HEADER/CHECK
> -----: | :--------- | -----------: | -----------: | -----------: | -----------:
>      1 | 2348657    |            1 |            0 |            0 |            0
>     10 | 4221860    |            1 |            0 |            0 |            0
>      1 | 6969860    |            1 |            0 |            0 |            0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b0c6414132ee9d9c51ff0cce9b5a7e58)*

Comment: +1 for helping me further. Thank you for helping me refine and deconstruct my querie. Not the complete solution ,but that's my bad as my question is incomplete . Please see @Charlieface's answer for the solution.  Greetings !